# Regarding random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Prove that $$\Pr(X\geq a) \leq \frac{E[e^X]}{e^a}$$

where e is Napier's base.

Can I know what the question means and how to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of $e$ being referred to as Napier's base.

Back to topic: What you are looking for is [Chernoff's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), in a simplified form:

$$ \Pr(X \geq a) = \Pr(e^X \geq e^a) \leq \frac{E[e^X]}{e^a}$$

First equality follows from monotonicity of the exponential function, while the inequality is an application of [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality).